# Handle table inside another HTML table without interfering with JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with `id="mytabla"`, which inside contains several data, and in the last row a field called retentions that should show another table inside, in this I have no problems, thus:

```
<table id="mytabla" class="table table-sm table-striped">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th id="#">#</th>
                <th id="Documento" class="tb-gra">Documento</th>
                <th id="Fecha">Fecha(emision)</th>
                <th id="retenciones">Retenciones</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tb-neg">1</td>
                <td class="tb-gra">FACTURA</td>
                <td style="width:64pt">04/06/2018</td>
                <td>SIN RETENCION</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tb-neg">1</td>
                <td class="tb-gra">FACTURA</td>
                <td style="width:64pt">04/06/2018</td>
                <td>SIN RETENCION</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tb-neg">1</td>
                <td class="tb-gra">FACTURA</td>
                <td style="width:64pt">04/06/2018</td>
                <td>
                     <table><tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>IVA</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>120.00</td>
                            <td>100.0</td>
                            <td>120.00</td>
                       </tr>
                     </tbody></table>
                </td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

in javascript I want to select the table and count the rows, but also tell me those of the second table, as I do so that the second table does not count or do not take it into account, I use this code:

```
var table = document.getElementById("mytabla");
var fila=document.getElementById("mytabla").getElementsByTagName('tr');
var row=table.insertRow(parseInt(fila.length);
var cantidaddefilas=fila.length;
```

but he is telling me those of the second table, as I do so that he does not count those.

Comment: You forgot to translate the last line into english. I would edit it but I don't want to change the meaning of what you want.

Comment: this is correct, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll` like in the example snippet below.

```js
var fila=document.querySelectorAll("#mytabla > tbody > tr");
alert('Number of rows: '+fila.length);
```

```html
<table id="mytabla" class="table table-sm table-striped">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th id="#">#</th>
                <th id="Documento" class="tb-gra">Documento</th>
                <th id="Fecha">Fecha(emision)</th>
                <th id="retenciones">Retenciones</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tb-neg">1</td>
                <td class="tb-gra">FACTURA</td>
                <td style="width:64pt">04/06/2018</td>
                <td>SIN RETENCION</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tb-neg">1</td>
                <td class="tb-gra">FACTURA</td>
                <td style="width:64pt">04/06/2018</td>
                <td>SIN RETENCION</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tb-neg">1</td>
                <td class="tb-gra">FACTURA</td>
                <td style="width:64pt">04/06/2018</td>
                <td>
                     <table><tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>IVA</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>120.00</td>
                            <td>100.0</td>
                            <td>120.00</td>
                       </tr>
                     </tbody></table>
                </td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

OR you could use `getElementsByClassName` after changing your `HTML` a little. Check this example also.

```js
var fila = document.getElementsByClassName('mytabla');
alert('Number of rows: '+fila.length);
```

```html
<table id="mytabla" class="table table-sm table-striped">
            <tbody>
            <tr class="mytabla">
                <th id="#">#</th>
                <th id="Documento" class="tb-gra">Documento</th>
                <th id="Fecha">Fecha(emision)</th>
                <th id="retenciones">Retenciones</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="mytabla">
                <td class="tb-neg">1</td>
                <td class="tb-gra">FACTURA</td>
                <td style="width:64pt">04/06/2018</td>
                <td>SIN RETENCION</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="mytabla">
                <td class="tb-neg">1</td>
                <td class="tb-gra">FACTURA</td>
                <td style="width:64pt">04/06/2018</td>
                <td>SIN RETENCION</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="mytabla">
                <td class="tb-neg">1</td>
                <td class="tb-gra">FACTURA</td>
                <td style="width:64pt">04/06/2018</td>
                <td>
                     <table><tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>IVA</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>120.00</td>
                            <td>100.0</td>
                            <td>120.00</td>
                       </tr>
                     </tbody></table>
                </td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

in case you don't want to count header row change your `HTML` by using a `thead` element.

```js
var fila=document.querySelectorAll("#mytabla > tbody > tr");
alert('Number of rows: '+fila.length);
```

```html
<table id="mytabla" class="table table-sm table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th id="#">#</th>
                <th id="Documento" class="tb-gra">Documento</th>
                <th id="Fecha">Fecha(emision)</th>
                <th id="retenciones">Retenciones</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="tb-neg">1</td>
                <td class="tb-gra">FACTURA</td>
                <td style="width:64pt">04/06/2018</td>
                <td>SIN RETENCION</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tb-neg">1</td>
                <td class="tb-gra">FACTURA</td>
                <td style="width:64pt">04/06/2018</td>
                <td>SIN RETENCION</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tb-neg">1</td>
                <td class="tb-gra">FACTURA</td>
                <td style="width:64pt">04/06/2018</td>
                <td>
                     <table><tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>IVA</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>120.00</td>
                            <td>100.0</td>
                            <td>120.00</td>
                       </tr>
                     </tbody></table>
                </td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `querySelector`.

```
document.querySelectorAll('#mytabla > tbody > tr');//selects all table rows whose parent is a tbody that is a child of #mytabla
```

```html
<table id="mytabla" class="table table-sm table-striped">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th id="#">#</th>
                <th id="Documento" class="tb-gra">Documento</th>
                <th id="Fecha">Fecha(emision)</th>
                <th id="retenciones">Retenciones</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tb-neg">1</td>
                <td class="tb-gra">FACTURA</td>
                <td style="width:64pt">04/06/2018</td>
                <td>SIN RETENCION</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tb-neg">1</td>
                <td class="tb-gra">FACTURA</td>
                <td style="width:64pt">04/06/2018</td>
                <td>SIN RETENCION</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tb-neg">1</td>
                <td class="tb-gra">FACTURA</td>
                <td style="width:64pt">04/06/2018</td>
                <td>
                     <table><tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>IVA</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>120.00</td>
                            <td>100.0</td>
                            <td>120.00</td>
                       </tr>
                     </tbody></table>
                </td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script>
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('#mytabla > tbody > tr').length);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure that I understand question. You want to count all rows, except rows in inner table?
Then, instead of

```
var fila=document.getElementById("mytabla").getElementsByTagName('tr');
```

use

```
var fila=document.querySelectorAll("#mytabla > tbody > tr");
```

Also, you don't need to `parseInt(fila.length)`. Length property is a number, so `fila.length` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a `table`, you can actually just get the length of its `rows` attribute https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_table_rows.asp

```
var cantidaddefilas = document.getElementById('mytabla').rows.length
```